# Bad request : Send string from Android client to .NET REST service

Tags: android, .net, rest

I am trying to send a json string from my android client (Android 4.03)
to my .net Rest service (WCF). And I got "Bad Request" as a response. I have .NET tester for this service and it works fine.

Server side code :

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "submit", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public bool SubmitPackage(string instance)
{      

 log.WriteWarning("Submit");
 return true;
}
```

My WCF config

```
<standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint name="" maxReceivedMessageSize="327680" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" transferMode="Buffered" />
    </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

My code on Android client

```
HttpPost request2 = new HttpPost(URL_Submit);
request2.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

JSONStringer json1 = new JSONStringer().object().key("instance")
                .value("hello world").endObject();


StringEntity entity1 = new StringEntity(json1.toString());
entity1.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
entity1.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

request2.setEntity(entity1);
// Send request to WCF service
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String response1 = httpClient.execute(request2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your WCF service hosted in IIS? Turn on failed request logging and have a look at the result of that.

Also use fiddler to look at the traffic being sent. You can configure fiddler to run on the server. It normally runs on the client, but you cannot run it on Android.

To configure fiddler to run on the server,

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp

Also I often put this in my web.config,

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\logs\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Which logs errors relating to requests. This can be opened up and the request dissected.